# Executing script even if they are failures in yml file

Tags: aws-codebuild

Hi All I am tying to setup a RestAPI pipeline in aws codebuild. I have custom Newman docker. I have a build command that will failure but I want to execute the rest of the commands as well. but shell stops executions other commands when the Newman command fails. how to execute other commands in yml file.

Comment: How is this related to [tag:jenkins]?

Answer (score 0):

One simple way would be:

1. You can create a custom shell script (mycommand.sh) with your command that can cause error inside a try catch statement (so that it will not result in an error)
2. In your Code build's yml file under commands section, just execute the ./mycommand.sh

Source:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-env-ref-cmd.html